# Four digit Pin Entry/ OTP screen in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, mobility

Can anyone suggest me how to create a 4 digit pin entry screen like One time password, User will enter and one circle will be checked/darken.

I know I can create this by using images and hidden text field. But I am unable to decide best way for the same.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Create a textfield with secueTextentry enabled and when user enters the key match the user id and the OTP for the user in your WS or DB .

Comment: Try this:- https://github.com/Datt1994/DPOTPView

Answer (score 3):

Imagine you have a `UITextField`. Getting the user's input to show up as black dots (and not expose their information) is as easy as doing this (assuming the `UITextField` is called `field`, and that you're using Swift).

```
field.secureTextEntry = true
```

Honestly I'm not totally sure what you're asking but this is my best guess.

Comment: No,You did not get me,, A Full screen is to be created with No text fields, what user will be able o see is a dark circle every time he taps a letter from keyboard.

Comment: @SundeepSaluja oh so you want like four boxes that will fill with dark circles as the user enters his PIN from a number pad?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess to achieve this using image. You can simply add image on your UITextField's subview.

```
 func addImageToTextField(txtPin : UITextField)
    {
        let imageView = UIImageView();

        let image = UIImage(named: "darkImage.png");

        imageView.image = image;

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: txtPin.frame.width, height: txtPin.frame.height)

        txtPin.addSubview(imageView)

    }
```

And call this method from `textFieldshouldChangeCharactersInRange`

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        textField.textColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        if (!string.isEmpty) {

            self.addImageToTextField(textField)
         }
```

Similarly you can do the same if user hits back button to clear the textfield

I have done this and works like a charm for me. Cheers !! happy coding.